# iOS: UISplitViewController Back Button Setup Query

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I've been struggling for ages trying to change the label of the back button in a UISplitViewController.

This is the only solution I could come up with. Basically stripping out the Target and Action from .displayModeButtonItem() and using it with my own UIBarButtonItem

```
var backButton = UIBarButtonItem()
if var b = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem() {
    backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "< back", style: .Plain, target: b.target, action: b.action)
}
```

I then use this button in my Segue connections like this:

```
if let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as UINavigationController).topViewController as? ManageViewController {
    controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
}
```

It works but I just have 2 issues with this:

1) When I set the title I lose the "<" symbol. As you can see i've tried to add this manually but it doesn't look as good. Is there anyway to get the usual "<" next to the label?

2) This feels like a bit of a hack. Am I ok to set it up like this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer I wrote in response to this SO question... [How to name a back button in UISplitViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31318847/how-to-name-a-back-button-in-uisplitviewcontroller).

Thanks to Paul Hegarty and his invaluable lectures at Stanford University and available on iTunes U... in this case his 2013 lectures under the title ["Developing iOS 7 Apps for iPhone and iPad"](https://itunes.apple.com/au/course/developing-ios-7-apps-for/id733644550) and specifically "Lecture 11 Table View and the iPad".

If you're using storyboards, then:

- Open your main storyboard and select the Navigation Controller that links to the Master View Controller in your Split View Controller group;
- Open the Inspector;
- Under the heading **View Controller**, against the property **Title**, enter the words that you would like to appear alongside the "Back" button chevron.

See screenshot of Master Detail Xcode template set up with a Split View Controller...

[image: Interface Building screenshot detailing location of "Title" property for Navigation Controller]

If you're instantiating views in code, then:

- obtain a reference to the Navigation Controller for the Master View controller;
- set the title property of that Navigation Controller with the `NSString` of words that you would like to appear alongside the "Back" button chevron.

As an aside, I would highly recommend implementation of Auto Layout and Size Classes, that you remove the text for the **Back Button** property and let size classes determine the appropriate words for your Back Button.

For example...

[image: remove text in the "Back Button" property]

Answer (score -1):

the answer is pretty simple what you have to do is go to the master class of your splitview controller and you write this`override fun viewdidload()
super.viewdidload()
navigationitem.title = “whateveryouwant”`
here i am assuming you are working with tableview if not then dont forget to give parameter in viewdidload method