# How to name a back button in UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I have `UITableViewController` (its name is News) and `UIViewController` (its name is DetailViewController) and `UISplitViewController`. I want it to show a back button when I use an iPad in portrait orientation. I made the button but I cannot name it. I wrote following code

```
detailController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem()
                detailController.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
                detailController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.title = navigationController?.topViewController.title
```

But it doesn't show the name of the button. I see only the arrow (the arrow works).

I also tried the following in my UITableViewController(News) but it didn't help me

[image]

I use two segues for different devices with this code.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
        var screen = UIScreen.mainScreen().currentMode?.size.height
        if (UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad) || screen >= 2000 && UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.isLandscape == true  && (UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone){
            performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetailParse", sender: nil)
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        } else if (UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone) {
            performSegueWithIdentifier("showParse", sender: nil)
        }
    }
```

My result on an iPad
[image]

My result on an iPhone
[image]

Comment: set a title on the previous view controller. it becomes the back button title for the next view controller

Comment: I made it like on my screenshot. @rounak

Comment: It works for me only I use an iPhone. @rounak

Comment: I have the same problem in just one screen and I can not found solution. In my case always show Back.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Thanks to Paul Hegarty and his invaluable lectures at Stanford University and available on iTunes U... in this case his 2013 lectures under the title ["Developing iOS 7 Apps for iPhone and iPad"](https://itunes.apple.com/au/course/developing-ios-7-apps-for/id733644550) and specifically "Lecture 11 Table View and the iPad".

If you're using storyboards, then:

- Open your main storyboard and select the Navigation Controller that links to the Master View Controller in your Split View Controller group;
- Open the Inspector;
- Under the heading **View Controller**, against the property **Title**, enter the words that you would like to appear alongside the "Back" button chevron.

See screenshot of Master Detail Xcode template set up with a Split View Controller...

[image: Interface Building screenshot detailing location of "Title" property for Navigation Controller]

If you're instantiating views in code, then:

- obtain a reference to the Navigation Controller for the Master View controller;
- set the title property of that Navigation Controller with the `NSString` of words that you would like to appear alongside the "Back" button chevron.

As an aside, I would highly recommend implementation of Auto Layout and Size Classes, that you remove the text for the **Back Button** property and let size classes determine the appropriate words for your Back Button.

For example, as per the question...

[image: remove text in the "Back Button" property]

Answer (score 4):

## The Solution:

Here is the way to fix the issue with the *detail* view controller's back button:

- For any view controller that gets pushed onto the *primary* navigation controller's stack, set that *view controller's* `title`. (Either in its `viewDidLoad:` method or in the pushing view controller's `prepareForSegue:sender:` method.)
- Set the *primary navigation controller's* `title` in the child view controller's `viewDidLoad:` method.

For example, in `MasterViewController.m`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self setTitle:@"Foo"];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [[self navigationController] setTitle:[self title]];
}
```

This will keep the detail view controller's back button title in sync with the top primary view controller's title.

## What Is Going On:

`UINavigationController`, its `rootViewController`, and `UINavigationItem` each have a `title` property.

Note that [the back button shown for a current view controller is actually the previous view controller's `backButtonItem`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH2-SW15). (See Figure 1-7 Navigation bar structure)

A `UINavigationController` will automatically inherit the value of the `title` of its root view controller, but **will not automatically inherit the title of any other controller that gets pushed** onto its stack. This is why, by default, the back button of the *detail* view controller will always show the title of the *primary* navigation controller's *root* view controller. You might allocate, initialize, and push multiple child view controllers, but only one navigation controller is allocated and initialized for each side of a standard split view controller.

Additionally, a view controller's `navigationItem`'s `title` property (whose value will appear in the label in the center of the navigation bar) **does not inherit its value from the navigation controller**, but from the view controller itself. If you set the view controller's `title` property to "Bar", and the containing navigation controller's title to "Foo", the label displayed in the center of the navigation bar will say "Bar".

Comment: This is a great solution. Thanks!  My DetailViewController back button (on iPad in Horizontal mode with Primary hidden with displayModeButton) was displaying the Primary Navigation Controllers rootViewController title all the time.  Even though I had pushed another childView onto the navigation stack. Glad I found this great explanation.